# Skype For Business Login Popup

Tags: c#, .net, skype-for-business

I have an application that uses Skype For Business in UI suppression mode.

When logging in using the following code (in UI suppressed):

```
await Task.Factory.FromAsync((callback, stateObject) => _client.BeginSignIn(config.SkypeUserUri, config.SkypeDomainAndUsername, config.SkypePassword, callback, stateObject), _client.EndSignIn, null);
```

The application just hangs and never gets any further.

If I try the same code without UI suppression. I'm seeing this pop-up password request. Rather than the normal password window Skype For Business uses.

[image]

It appears this pop-up is preventing the Skype From Business SDK from logging in. I have checked the credentials and everything seems okay. I don't seem to be able to get past it.

Any ideas what is going on here?

I believe this guy might be having the same issue: [Lync Client SDK - Ui suppression - Client stuck at SigningIn State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043790/lync-client-sdk-ui-suppression-client-stuck-at-signingin-state)

Comment: We are seeing this occurring for more and more clients. This appears to be the result of something Microsoft are rolling out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if:
1) ModernAuthentication is enabled in your office365 tenant
2) EnableADAL = 1 if you are using SkypeForBusiness2015 client 2015
3) If you are using SkypeForBusiness2016 client

Applicable only to SfB prior to 2016
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Identity\EnableADAL
If you want to bypass this pop-up, then you need to add EnableADAL registry key and set its value to 0.

Comment: By default with SfB2016, EnableADAL registry key is added, however with SfB2015 you will have to add it manually. If EnableADAL key is absent or set with value 1, then you have enabled ModernAuth. This is applicable with SfB2016, with SfB 2015 this registry key must be present and set with value 1.